# asymptotic of a determinant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, asymptotics, determinant

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Can one obtain an asymptotic (as $n\to+\infty$) of $\log|\det(M_n)|$ where $M_n=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{n+i-j}\end{pmatrix}_{0\le i,j\le n-1}$?

Tests with Xcas seem to indicate that $\log|\det(M_n)|\underset{n\to°\infty}{\sim}-n\log(n)$ but I can not prove it.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix $M_n$ is the Hilbert matrix $H_n = \left(\dfrac{1}{i+j+1}\right)_{0 \le i,j \le n-1}$ but flipped horizontally. Hence, $|\det(M_n)| = |\det(H_n)|$ for all $n$.

From the Wikipedia article on the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), the determinant of the Hilbert matrix has the closed form $$\det(H_n) = \dfrac{c_n^4}{c_{2n}} \quad \text{where} \quad c_n = \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1}i^{n-i} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1}i!,$$ and one can use Stirling's approximation to show that $$\det(H_n) = a_nn^{-1/4}(2\pi)^n4^{-n^2}$$ where $a_n$ converges to a constant. Hence, $$\log|\det(M_n)| = \log|\det(H_n)| = -n^2\ln 4 + n \ln(2\pi)-\tfrac{1}{4}\ln n + \ln a_n,$$ and thus, $\log|\det(M_n)| \sim -n^2\ln 4$ as $n \to \infty$. This isn't the same as the asymptotic result you got.

Comment: Thank you for this very precise answer.